# Как передать в explicit конструктор параметры?

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

В конструктор класса `QPushButton` можно передать строку. Если я напишу так, то всё будет хорошо: `QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("text")`, но я не хочу создавать указатель, а хочу создать переменную и просто написать `QPushButton button("text")`, но получаю ошибки *expected identifier before string constant* и *expected ',' or '...' before string constant*

```
#include <QPushButton>
class test
{
public:
    test();

private:
    QPushButton button1; // ok
    QPushButton button2("test"); // errors
};
```

Comment: "Не вижу препятствий!" (с)

Comment: можно, но целесообразность этого под вопросом...

Comment: @Fat-Zer и этот вопрос - второй :)

Comment: Заголовок не соответствует содержимому вопроса.

Comment: @Harry при такой записи выдаёт ошибки

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Так а что вы их не приводите?

Comment: @VTT добавил в вопрос

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Теперь осталось только добавить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Есть ощущение, что у вас где-то опечатка в коде.

Comment: вы кнопку инициализируете в теле класса - это нужно делать в конструкторе или  инициализировать используя фигурные скобки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При инициализации нестатического поля класса непосредственно в теле класса (да и вообще всегда) следует использовать синтаксис [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

```
class test
{
public:
  test();

private:
  QPushButton button1; // ok
  QPushButton button2{"test"}; // ok
};
```

Comment: Спасибо. Прошу прощения, что вопрос оформлял по частям

Comment: А почему через круглые скобки я не могу инициализировать поля в теле класса, но могу внутри какого-нибудь метода?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Потому для инициализации полей внутри класса может использоваться только синтаксис list initialization. Такие правила.